# How to fix MockitoExtension.class not resolved error

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5

I have recently migrated from JUnit4 to JUnit5. I have updated and edited my POM files (multiple POMs because my project is a multi-maven project).

It seems that my IDE (IntellIj Idea) is resolving JUnit 5 annotations. They are all available and functional.

But, when I am trying to annotate `OwnerSDJpaServiceTest` with `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`, IntellIj keeps telling me that it
"cannot resolve symbol 'MockitoExtension'.

To me, it looks like I am missing some dependencies but I have looked
at youtube videos and some documentations and it looks all good to me. So I don't know where might the real problem be.

Maybe I am missing a dependency or I have a misconfigured POM files.

If you need to see the whole app please use this link to [my GitHub repo](https://github.com/sajmon2325/Spring-Pet-Clinic.git).

Here is my root pom file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>guru.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>sfg-pet-clinic</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.5-SNAPSHOT</version>

        <modules>
            <module>pet-clinic-data</module>
            <module>pet-clinic-web</module>
        </modules>

        <packaging>pom</packaging>

        <name>sfg-pet-clinic</name>
        <description>SFG Pet Clinic Project</description>

        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>

        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF 8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        </properties>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <goals>install</goals>
                        <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>

        </build>

        <scm>
            <developerConnection>scm:git:https://github.com/sajmon2325/Spring-Pet-Clinic.git</developerConnection>
          <tag>HEAD</tag>
      </scm>

    </project>
```

Here is my pet-clinic-data pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>sfg-pet-clinic</artifactId>
        <groupId>guru.springframework</groupId>
        <version>0.0.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>pet-clinic-data</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <spring.boot.repackage.skip>true</spring.boot.repackage.skip>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.23.1-GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
                        <version>2.27.0</version>
                        <scope>runtime</scope>
                    </dependency>


                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is my pet-clinic data pom file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>sfg-pet-clinic</artifactId>
        <groupId>guru.springframework</groupId>
        <version>0.0.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>pet-clinic-data</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <spring.boot.repackage.skip>true</spring.boot.repackage.skip>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.23.1-GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
                        <version>2.27.0</version>
                        <scope>runtime</scope>
                    </dependency>


                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And finally here is my pet-clinic-web pom file (which is probably missing a dependency):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>sfg-pet-clinic</artifactId>
        <groupId>guru.springframework</groupId>
        <version>0.0.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>pet-clinic-web</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <!-- Web dependencies -->
        <webjars-bootstrap.version>3.3.6</webjars-bootstrap.version>
        <webjars-jquery-ui.version>1.11.4</webjars-jquery-ui.version>
        <webjars-jquery.version>2.2.4</webjars-jquery.version>
        <wro4j.version>1.8.0</wro4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>pet-clinic-data</artifactId>
            <groupId>guru.springframework</groupId>
            <version>0.0.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- webjars -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>${webjars-jquery.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${webjars-jquery-ui.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>${webjars-bootstrap.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- end of webjars -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>wro4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${wro4j.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <wroManagerFactory>ro.isdc.wro.maven.plugin.manager.factory.ConfigurableWroManagerFactory</wroManagerFactory>
                    <cssDestinationFolder>${project.build.directory}/classes/static/resources/css</cssDestinationFolder>
                    <wroFile>${basedir}/src/main/wro/wro.xml</wroFile>
                    <extraConfigFile>${basedir}/src/main/wro/wro.properties</extraConfigFile>
                    <contextFolder>${basedir}/src/main/less</contextFolder>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
                        <version>${webjars-bootstrap.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
                        <version>2.23.4</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
                        <version>2.27.0</version>
                        <scope>runtime</scope>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is my test class (which has the problem of not resolved symbol in MockitoExtension.class):

```
package guru.springframework.sfgpetclinic.services.springdatajpa;

import guru.springframework.sfgpetclinic.repositories.OwnerRepository;
import guru.springframework.sfgpetclinic.repositories.PetRepository;
import guru.springframework.sfgpetclinic.repositories.PetTypeRepository;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class OwnerSDJpaServiceTest {

    OwnerRepository ownerRepository;
    PetRepository petRepository;
    PetTypeRepository petTypeRepository;

    OwnerSDJpaService service;


    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {

    }

    @Test
    void findByLastName() {
    }

    @Test
    void findAll() {
    }

    @Test
    void findById() {
    }

    @Test
    void save() {
    }

    @Test
    void delete() {
    }

    @Test
    void deleteById() {
    }
}
```

I expect that the annotation is reckognized by IntellIj so I can test this class using JUnit5.

Comment: try adding [mockito-jupiter-extension](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-junit-jupiter) to your pom.

Comment: I have added this dependency into web and data pom.xml files but it still does not reckognizes the MockitoExtension.class parameter inside @ExtendWith()

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had the same problem in a simple test project and it turned out that I have only added the [core artifact:](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core)

```
org.mockito:mockito-core
```

and I also needed to add the [one that contains the extension for jUnit5](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-junit-jupiter/):

```
org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter
```

Comment: thanks for reply.
Yes this was the root of this problem

Comment: This solution works. I also missed this dependency

Answer (score 4):

In my pom.xml  (I left to the `version` if is already used for other dependency).

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

But, still the class was not found.!

In my class I was testing with:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;

@ExtendWith(org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension.class)
public class MyClassTest {
    //...
}
```

And it stopped asking for the import....

Then, I put manually the import, then `Secondary Click` -> `Source` -> `Organize Imports`.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MyClassTest {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your test folder as MokitoExtension.java

```
package com.pluralsight.tddjunit5;

 import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext;
 import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext.Namespace;
 import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext.Store;
 import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterContext;
 import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolver;
 import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.TestInstancePostProcessor;
 import org.mockito.Mock;
 import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

 import java.lang.reflect.Parameter;

 import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

public class MockitoExtension
    implements TestInstancePostProcessor, ParameterResolver {

@Override
public void postProcessTestInstance(Object testInstance,
        ExtensionContext context) {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(testInstance);
}

@Override
public boolean supportsParameter(ParameterContext parameterContext,
        ExtensionContext extensionContext) {
    return parameterContext.getParameter().isAnnotationPresent(Mock.class);
}

@Override
public Object resolveParameter(ParameterContext parameterContext,
        ExtensionContext extensionContext) {
    return getMock(parameterContext.getParameter(), extensionContext);
}

private Object getMock(Parameter parameter,
        ExtensionContext extensionContext) {
    Class<?> mockType = parameter.getType();
    Store mocks = extensionContext
            .getStore(Namespace.create(MockitoExtension.class, mockType));
    String mockName = getMockName(parameter);

    if (mockName != null) {
        return mocks.getOrComputeIfAbsent(mockName,
                key -> mock(mockType, mockName));
    } else {
        return mocks.getOrComputeIfAbsent(mockType.getCanonicalName(),
                key -> mock(mockType));
    }
}

private String getMockName(Parameter parameter) {
    String explicitMockName = parameter.getAnnotation(Mock.class).name()
            .trim();
    if (!explicitMockName.isEmpty()) {
        return explicitMockName;
    } else if (parameter.isNamePresent()) {
        return parameter.getName();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Gradle. The MockitoExtension class is actually in the mockito-junit-jupiter.jar file, therefore mockito-core is not required. See the screen clipping below:

[image]

Here is a screen clipping of my Gradle file:

[image]

Here is a link on an article that might help: https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with Junit5, you need to include this dependency `org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter`.
However, with Junit4, you don't need to use this extension and can achieve the same mocking behaviour by using Junit4's @RunWith and `MockitoJUnitRunner.class`. But in Junit5, there are no rules and runners. hence you cannot use `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` or Rules in Junit5.

Answer (score -1):

I have solved that problem by editing my web pom.xml file to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>sfg-pet-clinic</artifactId>
        <groupId>guru.springframework</groupId>
        <version>0.0.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>pet-clinic-web</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <!-- Web dependencies -->
        <webjars-bootstrap.version>3.3.6</webjars-bootstrap.version>
        <webjars-jquery-ui.version>1.11.4</webjars-jquery-ui.version>
        <webjars-jquery.version>2.2.4</webjars-jquery.version>
        <wro4j.version>1.8.0</wro4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>pet-clinic-data</artifactId>
            <groupId>guru.springframework</groupId>
            <version>0.0.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>lombok</artifactId>-->
        <!--<optional>true</optional>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- webjars -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>${webjars-jquery.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${webjars-jquery-ui.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>${webjars-bootstrap.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- end of webjars -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>wro4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${wro4j.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <wroManagerFactory>ro.isdc.wro.maven.plugin.manager.factory.ConfigurableWroManagerFactory</wroManagerFactory>
                    <cssDestinationFolder>${project.build.directory}/classes/static/resources/css</cssDestinationFolder>
                    <wroFile>${basedir}/src/main/wro/wro.xml</wroFile>
                    <extraConfigFile>${basedir}/src/main/wro/wro.properties</extraConfigFile>
                    <contextFolder>${basedir}/src/main/less</contextFolder>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
                        <version>${webjars-bootstrap.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you had to change ?

Comment: Hi, It has been long time since I had this problem so I cant tell you exactly what have I changed.
But you can compare my <artifactId>pet-clinic-web</artifactId> pom at the top of this post with the pet-clinic-web pom.xml that I have under Answer section and see the difference